# Changing unix timestamp back to mysql datetime using get_post_meta

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that converts my get_post_meta from the database into unix, compared the variable to another variable and if it has different unix times, it will write it back to the database.

> `$wp_modified = strtotime(get_post_meta($office->ID, '_last_modified', true));`
>   **Outputs**:
>   2018-10-30 00:02:00 to 1571304301

Then below, I need to turn the _last_modified post meta back to the `2018-10-30 00:02:00` format before writing with update_post_meta.

> ```
> if ($time_changed) {
>     update_post_meta($office->ID, '_last_modified', $record->updated_at);
> }
> ```

How would I be able to change it back from 1571304301 to 2018-10-30 00:02:00 before executing the `update_post_meta($office->ID, '_last_modified', $record->updated_at);` call?

Do I do something like this?

```
    if ($time_changed) {
        $test = get_post_meta($office->ID, '_last_modified', true);
        $test1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $test);
        update_post_meta($office->ID, '_last_modified', $test1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working:

```
if ($time_changed) {
    $wp_modified_back = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $record->updated_at);
    update_post_meta($office->ID, '_last_modified', $wp_modified_back);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL you have functions that will help you with UNIX timestamps, Ex.:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(1540872120), unix_timestamp("2018-10-30 00:02:00")
```

With this you can use MySQL results directly and forget about converting in PHP.

For PHP:

I think the code you have: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1540872120)` would do the trick.